# How to configure Makefile to use OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, makefile

I installed opencv in RaspberryPi and configured Makefile but it can't find header files.
How to configure Makefile correctly?

I have 2 `.cpp` files and 1 `.h` file.

```
BlobLabeling.cpp  BlobLabeling.h  hand_tracking.cpp
```

When I run make, it returns the following:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~/test $ make
g++ BlobLabeling.cpp
In file included from BlobLabeling.cpp:2:0:
BlobLabeling.h:9:31: fatal error: highgui/highgui.hpp: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
Makefile:11: recipe for target 'BlobLabeling.o' failed
make: *** [BlobLabeling.o] Error 1
```

---

**in BlobLabeling.cpp**

```
#include "BlobLabeling.h"
```

**in hand_tracking.cpp**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "cv.h"
#include "highgui.h"
#include "BlobLabeling.h"
```

**in BlobLabeling.h**

```
#include "highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv.hpp"
```

**Makefile**

```
CXX = g++

LDFLAGS = -lopencv_legacy -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_core -lopencv_ml -lopencv_video -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_objdetect -L/usr/lib

CPPFLAGS = -g -I/usr/include/opencv -I/usr/include/opencv2

all: BlobLabeling.o hand_tracking.o
        g++ -o test BlobLabeling.o hand_tracking.o

BlobLabeling.o: BlobLabeling.cpp
        g++ BlobLabeling.cpp

hand_tracking.o: hand_tracking.cpp BlobLabeling.h
        g++ hand_tracking.cpp
```

**in /usr/include/opencv2**

```
pi@raspberrypi ~/test $ ls /usr/include/opencv2
calib3d  features2d  imgproc  objdetect   stitching  videostab
contrib  flann       legacy   opencv.hpp  ts
core     highgui     ml       photo       video
```

Comment: can you try to use the proper "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp" and "opencv2/core/core.hpp" instead of the outdated "cv.h" and "highgui.h" ?

Comment: @berak thanks you! I changed "opencv2/highui/highgui.hpp", "opencv2"/opencv.hpp" in BlobLabeling.h and it works!

Comment: @berak Please add it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please use the proper c++ headers:

```
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
```

along with the include path:

```
-I/usr/include/opencv2
```

instead of the outdated "cv.h" and "highgui.h"

Comment: now its `#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>`